# Changing from primitive type int to class Integer

Tags: java, methods, integer, primitive-types

How can I modify this method so that class `Integer` is used instead of primitive type `int`?

```
int[][] fillMatrix() {
    int[][] matrix = new int[5][4];
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
            matrix[row][column] = row * column;
   return matrix;
}
```

Comment: rewrite your code and replace int with Integer ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @ControlAltDel he may want null values in the matrix ?

Comment: @StackFlowed fair enough

Comment: @ControlAltDel its for an assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
Integer[][] fillMatrix() {
Integer[][] matrix = new Integer[5][4];
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    for (int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
        matrix[row][column] = row * column;
 return matrix;
}
```

Comment: Adding a comment noting the auto-boxing would make me a lot happier